# Laravel notification facebook driver get fb_messenger_user_id

Tags: laravel, facebook, facebook-messenger-bot, laravel-notification

I want to give users the ability to get [notifications via the facebook messenger](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/facebook). However, I don't really know how to get the `fb_messenger_user_id` from a user.

I can get a personalized ID for the chat if a user starts chatting with my bot, but with this, I can't really verify which user that is. Is there something I've overseen? Something like a button similar to the "login with facebook" button?

Also, as far as I understand the docs, I am only allowed to send messages in a time frame of 24h after the last message from the user.

Can someone tell me how to use the facebook notifications properly?

As a side note: I am planning to implement botman into my existing app. I don't know how much this affects the notifications.

Comment: If you aren’t aware of what you can and can’t do, and how the whole Messenger API works - then I would suggest you start with the documentation for that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: I've read the documentation. But the documentation says "to send messages over the Messenger to someone, the conversation needs to be started from the user". So how exactily can I get the id from the user that is currently loged in?

Comment: When they send _you_ a message, you get their page-scoped user id, and that is the id you need to send them a message back. If you need to match this to an app-scoped id of the user that is currently logged into your app or website - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching